# Texture Paint: set cursor position stop working

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

In Texture Paint mode, I'm not able to set the cursor position of the clone tool.
The shortcut CTRL+LMB stopped working.

I'm using Blender 4.0.

I have tried:

- close and reopen the file
- check if the texture is selected in the shading tab
- check if the texture is selected in the UV editor
- check if the texture file is corrupted
- restore the preferences
- create a new texture file
- change the mesh (of the same blend file)

It seems like something that depends on this blend file. In my other models I can use the Texture Paint clone tool without any problems.

What can I do? Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Take a look here: if I hold CTRL+LMB and move the mouse, I'm able to drag the cursor

[image]

Instead in this file I can set the cursor position with "one click" (CTRL+LMB)

[image]

What is the difference? Why CRL+LMB doesn't work in the first file?

Drag the cursor is inconvenient to set the clone source.

Comment: See the Blender 4 manual [Texture Paint Tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/texture_paint/tools.html#texture-paint-tools) _Clone_ entry.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/paint-grab-clone-not-working/570214/3) will help you out: apparently that shortcut has been doubly assigned, and the functioning might overlap, which could cause the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Joachim. I didn't find any double shortcut assigned. Also, this issue occurs in only one of my blend files. It's not a general Blender issue.

Comment: See the new update, please. There is something of strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution!
The problem about setting the cursor position depends on Stroke configuration:

[image]

I don't know why I had this feature turned on, but you have to disable that option to get the clone tool working again!